# React Native 0.47 removed createJSModules method retrocompatibility

Tags: javascript, android, compatibility, react-native

I have a React Native native bridging module I coded and, as you may know, [version 0.47](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.47.0) of React Native made a breaking change for these :

```
Remove unused createJSModules calls (ce6fb33, 53d5504) - @javache
```

The thing is, now a project using RN 0.47 (or higher in the future) won't compile if this deprecated overriden method is in the `MainApplication.java` file of an Android module and a project using a lower version won't compile if it is not present.

How can I make a native module of my own compatible with older and newer versions than 0.47 with this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `@Override` Annotation of `createJSModules()` and it will work for both!